# Wordpress - Redirect users after click submit for review

Tags: wordpress, redirect, post, notice

I have this function with small JS to notice our users after their clicking submit for review.

How can i redirect them after alert is done to the post admin area.

```
function notify_me_for_pending() {
    global $post;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    //Check if we need to display alert
    if ($current_screen->base == 'post' && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trigger_notice', TRUE)) {
        $notice = __('Thank you for your submission, Your posts will be subjected to approval period, it may take 24-48h for approval.', 'themename'); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php echo 'alert("'.$notice.'");'; ?>
        </script><?php
         delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'trigger_notice'); //Alert is done now remove it.
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'notify_me_for_pending');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current function, you could just add a delay with `setTimeout` and use `window.location`, something like this perhaps:

```
function notify_me_for_pending() {
    global $post;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    //Check if we need to display alert
    if( $current_screen->base == 'post' && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'trigger_notice', TRUE ) ){
        $notice = __('Thank you for your submission, Your posts will be subjected to approval period, it may take 24-48h for approval.', 'themename');
        $admin_page = admin_url( 'edit.php' ); // Whichever Admin Page You'd Like ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert( <?php echo $notice; ?> );

            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location( <?php echo $admin_page; ?> );
            }, 2500 );
        </script>

        <?php delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'trigger_notice' ); //Alert is done now remove it.
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'notify_me_for_pending' );
```

You could also replace your `alert` with a `confirm`, and redirect when the user clicks `Okay`:

```
function notify_me_for_pending() {
    global $post;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    //Check if we need to display alert
    if( $current_screen->base == 'post' && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'trigger_notice', TRUE ) ){
        $notice = __('Thank you for your submission, Your posts will be subjected to approval period, it may take 24-48h for approval. Click "OK" to be redirected, or click "Cancel" to stay here.', 'themename');
        $admin_page = admin_url( 'edit.php' ); // Whichever Admin Page You'd Like ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            if( window.confirm( <?php echo $notice; ?> ) ){
                window.location( <?php echo $admin_page; ?> );
            }
        </script>

        <?php delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'trigger_notice' ); //Alert is done now remove it.
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'notify_me_for_pending' );
```

You could also make use of WordPress' native `admin_notice` functionality (though at the time of this post you'll need to hack together a solution for Gutenberg since by default it hides these notices)

```
function post_approval_notice(){
    global $post;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    //Check if we need to display alert
    if( $current_screen->base == 'post' && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'trigger_notice', TRUE ) ){ ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success">
            <p><?php __( 'Thank you for your submission, your post will be subjected to admin approval. Note it may take 24-48 hours for approval. <a href="'. admin_url( 'edit.php' ) .'">Click Here to Return</a>', 'themename' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'post_approval_notice' );
```

Or you could potentially even work the automatic redirect in there as well:

```
function post_approval_notice(){
    global $post;
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    $admin_page = admin_url( 'edit.php' ); // Whichever Admin Page You'd Like

    //Check if we need to display alert
    if( $current_screen->base == 'post' && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'trigger_notice', TRUE ) ){ ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success">
            <p><?php __( 'Thank you for your submission, your post will be subjected to admin approval. Note it may take 24-48 hours for approval.', 'themename' ); ?></p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location( <?php echo $admin_page; ?> );
            }, 2500 );
        </script>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'post_approval_notice' );
```